# How To Bind A DataTable To MS Chart

Tags: c#, sql, .net, charts, mschart

this is myCode:

```
 private void frmChart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmdSum = new SqlCommand("Select distinct(UserName),sum(Value) from mytable  group by UserName",Con);
            Con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmdSum.ExecuteReader();
            chart1.DataBindTable(reader,"sum(Value)");
        }
        foreach (Series series in chart1.Series)
        {
            series.CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=LightToDark";
        }

    }
```

It shows me an error in chart1.DatabindTable. also I try another method but I could not handle it.

Comment: Showing us exactly what the error is would help us help you. I would start by checking the exact name of the column that you want to bind to.

Comment: are you trying to plot one value for each distinct user?

Comment: @MongZhu yes, Thats is true.

Comment: @PaulF An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll

Additional information: Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series

Comment: @MongZhu thank you. Then I try to find another approach.

Comment: @MongZhu: If you check the documentation for SqlDataReader you will see that it is derived from DbDataReader which implements IEnumerable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx You can confirm with _"bool IsIEnumerable = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SqlDataReader));"_

Comment: @PaulF Thank you for this information. I haven't dug deep enough. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is to bind a data table, then just do this:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "your sql here";

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            chart1.DataBindTable(dt.DefaultView, "UserName");
        }
```

[image]

Note when calling `DataBindTable` you have to use "UserName" (`xField`). Not `Value` or `Sum(Value)`.

Comment: if I had two column instead of one, for example instead of username I had Sender and Receiver columns and I would like to show its value. is it possible to use the above code? if it is true, I will be so appreciated if you help me, cause I made a little change in above code but I could not get the result.

Comment: If you want to show Sender and Receiver in the same chart then you would need 2 separate series and then bind each one of them also separately. `DataBindTable` cannot do it for you, it can only bind one table to one series, which is the default series. The best thing for you to do is to post this new specific scenario as a new question. In case you haven't done it yet, please read how to ask a good question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so there will be plenty of people trying to help you.

Comment: Specifically you would have to do something like this: `chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(); chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBind();` You can see the doc for `DataBind()` [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.databind(v=vs.110).aspx), which is very similar to `DataBindTable`.

Answer (score 0):

check you values into reader.. if you have values,

try replacing

```
chart1.DataBindTable(reader,"sum(Value)");
```

with

```
chart1.DataBindTable(reader,"Value");
```

once you sum up values into query you need not to mention sum again, your Value parameter will have sum

Edit --- Updated Code..

```
private void frmChart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmdSum = new SqlCommand("Select distinct(UserName),sum(Value) from mytable  group by UserName", Con);
                Con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmdSum.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    chart1.DataBindTable(reader, reader["Value"]);
                }

            }
            foreach (Series series in chart1.Series)
            {
                series.CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle=LightToDark";
            }

        }
```

Comment: so what the output?

Comment: which chart are you using and c# what widows /wpf web ?

Comment: I added a column chart in a windows form app

Comment: it does not work, it shows another error about argument2 that can nor convert from object to string. I used tostring() to but its does not useful.