# DataTable to Graph - Using Points.AddXY or DataBind

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I tried the ideas from:
[Drawing a chart from a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588055/drawing-a-chart-from-a-datatable) and from [How To Bind A DataTable To MS Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298920/how-to-bind-a-datatable-to-ms-chart)

I am not sure if I am missing something silly or my case is different.

I have a `DataTable` named: `DataTableUsedToPlotGraph`. This `DataTable` contains several columns (for example, temp, time, time_formatted, foder_name...).

I want to plot the graph with the data of two columns of this `DataTable` (X - time column vs. Y - time column).

What I tried (It says that I need not only X points but also Y points; If I try to put x and y says: cannot convert from 'System.Data.dataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'):

```
ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].Points.DataBind(DataTableUsedToPlotGraph,"time");
```

or

```
ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].Points.DataBindXY(DataTableUsedToPlotGraph,"time", "temp");
```

Also,
(does not plot anything in my graph)

```
this.ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].Points.AddXY(DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp.Columns["time"].ToString(), DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp.Columns["temp"].ToString());
```

Then,

```
DataView dv1 = new DataView(DataTableUsedToPlotGraph);
DataView dv2 = new DataView(DataTableUsedToPlotGraph);

dv1.RowFilter = "time";
dv2.RowFilter = "temp";

ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].Points.DataBind(dv1, "time", "temp, "");
```

For the database access I use this:

```
try
{
    conDatabase.Open();
    myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].MarkerSize = 2;
        this.ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].Points.AddXY(myReader["time"].ToString(), myReader["temp"].ToString());
    }
} // end of try
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

But nothing is working. Does anybody know what am I missing?

After reading and getting a lot of help from @TaW, I tried, with no success (the graphing is showing but with no points):

```
    try
    {
        this.ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].Points.DataBindXY(DataTableUsedToPlotGraph.Rows, "temp", DataTableUsedToPlotGraph.Rows, "time");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Note: if I use the same columns with "SqlDataReader myReader;" , it works fine.

One more attempt (showing the graph but no points):

```
    DataTableReader myReader;
    try
    {
        myReader = DataTableUsedToPlotGraph.CreateDataReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            //ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].MarkerSize = 2;
            this.ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].Points.AddXY(myReader["time"].ToString(), myReader["temp"].ToString());

        }
    } // end of try
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

I Add a DGV to see if I have data:

```
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = DataTableUsedToPlotGraph;
    this.ChartTempVsTime.Series["TimeVsTempPoint"].Points.DataBindXY(DataTableUsedToPlotGraph.Rows, "temp", DataTableUsedToPlotGraph.Rows, "time");
```

the results contain data + columns name with time and temp. I will try to upload the image in some server.

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not a helpful problem description! - What happens? Nothing? Errors? Crashes? Wrong results? - Also: Can't you at least test to see if you have acutually the data you expected to select??

Comment: Also: Why do you convert the data to string? Chart are supposed to display numbers; the y-values will get converted by the system but the x-values will not!

Comment: @TaW , I edited my question. I hope that is clearly now. Also, I tried to make ToString() because if I do not "force", I get the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll". If I use ToString(), I pass this error - but I agree with you, graphs are only numbers and not string!

Comment: Sometimes x-values are strings (IDs, cities, other names); often they are DateTimes, but y-values never are. You could cast to the real type using Convert. What are the types of the x-values and of the y-values?

Comment: @TaW , I hope to get Time vs. Temp. In the X - Time (coming, from the Data Table as 4/26/2017 8:53:00 AM or  8:53 AM - I have two columns in the Data Table - I can use the column that is easier to plot (I prefer the full time one)). In the Y - Temp (temperature - ranging from 0 to +- 600 Celcius)

Comment: Note that the 1st link above is for a special problem, not your rather striaght-forward case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways for data-binding a Chart.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the various options and their respective pros and cons!

Here is a simple one: Given a `DataTable dt` with two suitable columns `"c0"` and `"c1"` you can simply write:

```
yourChart.Series[yourSeriesIndexOrName].Points.DataBindXY(dt.Rows, "c0", dt.Rows, "c1");
```

Note that if you want to have dates in the x-values it is best to select dates and make sure the table column is also `DateTime`.

Comment: This looks really nice but it is not plotting anything on my graph. My graph is showing but with no points. I double check to see if the DataTable contains the fields and information that I wanna plot - the information and columns are correct. What is strange, it is if I try almost in the same way with Data Base as a source, it works. I will Edit the questions with my results.

Comment: You may want to add a DGV for testing and give it the DataTable as its datasource..

Comment: Hey, I just did and for me, it seems right - the data is showing on the DGV and I have several columns where 2 of them are data and time.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of both, the dgv with some data and the chart. Does the chart show its axes? Also show the DataBindXY you use now..

Comment: Go it! It is working! I was cleaning the graph in another part of my code! Thank you.